# Why questions are no longer accepted from my account? Why am I getting "You have reached your question limit" while trying to post a new question?

Tags: support

While trying to ask a new question, I'm getting

> #### You have reached your question limit
>
> ---
>
> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

[image: You have reached ...]

What is the reason I can no longer ask questions?
What is wrong with [Error receiving Python 3.8.10 modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354156/error-receiving-python-3-8-10-modules)?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, what you're hitting is the system controls on content quality.

This is the total sum of your 10 question submissions, their votes, and which ones were deleted:

[image]

Of all 10, 5 have been downvoted.  Two have been deleted.  Of the two that were deleted, one was closed as requiring details, and then removed by the system.

Of the ten questions, 3 were closed as needing details.

**This block is implemented by the system, based on community acceptance of your posts, how many were closed/flagged, and how many were deleted by you.**

There is nothing implicitly wrong with your questions, but deleting your own questions **is seen as a negative mark in the system**.

Details on this automated system and how you can handle the situation are in the [Help Center topic about Question Bans](https://askubuntu.com/help/question-bans).

With the large number of closed and deleted questions, I would surmise that your questions are not containing requisite information necessary to address or solve the problem, and that you should focus on providing information requested in comments.  However, the system initiated squashing of your ability to post questions is **system implemented** and nobody can override that, not even the CMs who are SE staff.

Refer to the help center - improve your questions and interact positively and the system might let you go free.  However, there's no more action anyone can take on this, it's a system-implemented thing, not anything that Moderators or the Community can do.

Also, **[read this Meta.SE post in its entirety](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)**.  It explains what you can do to 'improve' your posts and how to handle this.

Comment: This is completely meaningless
If they are bad questions, why aren't they removed when I try to delete them !?

Comment: I can't voluntarily remove them. Maybe because they happened to be good questions. So this is not about questions, it is about me.

Comment: @BullShit This has nothing to do with you.  Your posts are not necessarily 'bad questions' you just need to go through and **provide details when requested in comments**.  However, the *deletion* of your own posts is likely also related to the trigger, if it's downvoted and then deleted, this tends to be an extra negative mark.  Contribute other ways, per the Meta.SE post, and EVENTUALLY restrictions may be lifted.  Don't assume this has to do with *you* though.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be anything wrong with your question about Python modules. You may be simply hit a rate limit.

Stack Exchange sites generally have rate-limiting in place, and the limit is determined on a number of factors. [This Meta answer from a few years back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900) goes into greater detail about the various limits that a person might run into. For your question, I'd recommend looking at the "Asking" bit, which says:

> - Users with < 125 rep on the current site, [40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265) (This applies to the user's IP address, not their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network; similarly, if the same user posts a question from a different IP address, [they may not be limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341711/377214).)
>
>   [image: Question limit - You can only post once every 40 minutes]
>
>   - Other per-site limits may apply; e.g. on Stack Overflow, new users can only ask once every 90 minutes. Some of these per-site limits do also check the account, not just the IP address.
>   - While the limit is waived for users with 125+ reputation on a given site, questions posted on sites where one has 125+ reputation still count toward the rate limit for sites where one doesn't. For instance, if you ask a question on a site where you have 150 rep, you can't ask another question on a site where you have only 100 rep for the next 40 minutes; however, you can ask them in reverse order immediately (first on the 100-rep site, then on the 150-rep site).
> - Users limited by Anti-Recidivism System, one question per week
> - Users limited from asking questions for 1 – 7 days based on the performance of their previous questions
> - Users prevented from asking questions due to the quality filter: one question per 6 months
> - Users with < 10k rep trip CAPTCHA* if more than once per 60 seconds, or within 5 seconds of starting new post
> - Users with ≥ 10k rep trip CAPTCHA* if more than once per 30 seconds, or within 5 seconds of starting new post
> - On Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and Mathematics (not active on all other sites)
>
>   - maximum of 6 questions per day
>   - maximum of 50 questions per 30 days, on a rolling basis (50 questions in past 720 hours before current time).
>
>   > Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period
> - Stack Exchange staff members are not subject to these rate limits on meta sites

AskUbuntu may or may not use some or all of these rules. From what I understand, the limits are opaque to everyone. That said, one effective way to reduce the limitations that you may face would be to become more active in the community and gain a higher reputation.

Comment: I have never asked a question that does not help others.
Although the solution to my problem today was solved. But since I did not ask the question, it will probably not help the others. Anyway, this behavior was very unprofessional. And I have nothing more to say here...

Comment: 407 people reached، My page proves this, my questions have helped others. However, some people seem to be reluctant to help others.

Comment: I no longer have any secrets to ask questions on this site.
I will delete the questions I have asked so far to prove that it does not matter

Comment: This is really ridiculous, because I can not delete the questions! Why !? Those that you think are bad questions, so why not remove them !? It makes no sense.

Comment: No, he's question blocked, not ratelimited.  Completely different system in place.  (cc @Kulfy for reasons)

Comment: @UbuntuRoid ***"407 people reached، My page proves this, my questions have helped others."***: May be not. All views are not from users who are seeking help or got redirected from search engine. They might be from lurkers (like me). Even a single person (even me & you) can single-handedly increase view counts significantly. It's just a guesstimate. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290491.

Comment: (Contd.) ***"... that you think are bad questions, so why not remove them"***: Questions are never bad. Though they may have bad formatting, irrelevant details and lack of research (not pointing out any post, just saying). And there is always a window for improvement :)

Comment: @Kulfy he's hard blocked from question posting - its a Question Ban, not a ratelimit or how he's reaching viewers.  My answer is the best on this.

Comment: @ThomasWard I understand that. I'm not even doubting the correctness of your answer. You already have my upvote. I was trying to point and clarify some things from questioner's comments since IMHO, there must be no space for false assumptions. My comments were not even related to the original post.